# How to store data in localStorage using Backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js, backbone.js-collections, backbone-local-storage

I'm new with backbone.js. How can I store data in my localstorage and retrieve them? I am using jeromegn's [Backbone.localStorage](https://github.com/jeromegn/Backbone.localStorage) but why can't I add or save it into the localstorage?

Here's my collection:

```
var Cases = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    localStorage: new Backbone.LocalStorage('dataObject'),
});
```

Here's my view:

```
var CreateCase = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '.case',
    render: function(){
        var template = _.template($('#create-case-view').html(), {});
        this.$el.html(template);
    },
    events: {
        'submit #caseForm': 'createCase',
        'click .back': 'returnBack',
        'focus #c_round': 'datePicker'
    },
    createCase: function(e){
        var caseDetails = $(e.currentTarget).serializeObject();
        var cases = new Cases();
        //console.log(caseDetails);
        cases.add(caseDetails, {
            success: function(cases){
                console.log(cases); //I CAN'T ADD/SAVE IT TO THE COLLECTION
                //router.navigate('', {trigger: true});
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
   });
```

When user submits the form it should be added to the collection.

How can I retrieve it from the collection? I used cases.fetch(); but there's no data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not aware of any version of Backbone which accepts a `success` callback for the [Collection.add](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-add) function. Based on your code, it looks like you want the [Collection.create](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-create) function instead, which will not only add your model, but also save it (i.e. perform the sync).

```
var Cases = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    localStorage: new Backbone.LocalStorage('dataObject'),
});

var cases = new Cases();

cases.create({caseNo: 1, caseName: 'another case'}, {
    success: function(caseModel){ // note, this is the model
        console.log(caseModel);
    }
});
```

See it in action here: https://jsfiddle.net/vbj2ouey/1/
 (due to sandboxing it only worked in JSFiddle)

Comment: thanks! how can i retrieve stored data in the localstorage i've used? i want to push the data in the localstorage whenever i clicked the create button, is that possible?